# Javascript combine arrays items with every item in other arrays as text

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array;`["Color", ["red", "blue"]]`

I want to combine the items of the color array with the items in these arrays items as text;

```
[
 ["Size", ["small", "medium", "large"]],
 ["Model", ["modern", "old"]]
]
```

And final result should be like this;

```
[
 "Color_red_Size_small_Model_modern",
 "Color_red_Size_small_Model_old",
 "Color_red_Size_medium_Model_modern",
 "Color_red_Size_medium_Model_old",
 "Color_red_Size_large_Model_modern",
 "Color_red_Size_large_Model_old",
 "Color_blue_Size_small_Model_modern",
 "Color_blue_Size_small_Model_old",
 "Color_blue_Size_medium_Model_modern",
 "Color_blue_Size_medium_Model_old",
 "Color_blue_Size_large_Model_modern",
 "Color_blue_Size_large_Model_old",
]
```

I couldn't make it. How would I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see a) that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first, and b) used a [mcve] to narrow down the problem. Asking SO to do all the work for you doesn't help you or us. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Using loops can help you

Comment: @cid I've been trying for hours but I tried to do it with loops but it didn't

Comment: Show us your best(s) attempt(s), you might be close to the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
function makeLabels (arr) {
  return arr.reduce((result, el) => {
    var first = el[0];
    var list = el[1];
    var newResult = [];
    if (result.length < 1) {
      list.forEach((val) => {
        newResult.push(first+"_"+val);
      });
    } else {
      result.forEach((r) => {
      
        list.forEach((val) => {
          newResult.push(r+"_"+first+"_"+val);
        });
      });
    }
    return newResult;
  }, []);
}

var properties =
  [ ["Color", ["red", "blue"]]
  , ["Size", ["small", "medium", "large"]]
  , ["Model", ["modern", "old"]] ];
  
console.log( makeLabels(properties) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a cartesian function for the values and map the keys in front of the values, then joing the arrays.

```js
const
    cartesian = (a, b) => a.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(b.map(w => [].concat(v, w))), []),
    data = [["Color", ["red", "blue"]], ["Size", ["small", "medium", "large"]], ["Model", ["modern", "old"]]],
    keys = data.map(([key]) => key),
    result = data
        .map(([, values]) => values)
        .reduce(cartesian)
        .map(a => a.map((v, i) => [keys[i], v].join('_')).join('_'));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This is nice way. I tried a very long solution for that, but it was only that simple thank you